# How to parse json file with nested, unkeyed arrays

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing

I'm new to Swift an json, but have to decode/parse the following json file (XCODE 10.1, MACos):

```
{"result":{
"3600":[[1619589600,54894.2,55019.7,54515,54660.8,104.41723222,5713178.066847375]]
},
"allowance":{
"cost":0,
"remaining":10,
"remainingPaid":9999999999,
"account":"cccccc6758e98d700f"
}
}
```

As a novice I don't know how to handle the double nested unkeyed array in the top. Thank you for your kind help!!

Comment: The type is `[[Double]]`

Comment: The latest Xcode is 12.5, why are you using 10.1?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/7/3/parsing-json-using-the-codable-protocol

Answer (score 1):

I assume by parse you mean to read the contents. What you are trying to read is not an "unkeyed" array. It is a 2-D array or an array inside a parent array. Consider how you access elements of an array A = [7,5,6,8,9]. So A[0] = 7, A[1] = 5 and so on.

Similarly, in your example, the child array is at the 0th index of the parent. So JSON['result']['3600'] will give you the parent and JSON['result']['3600'][0] will give you the child.

Comment: Thx a lot! Indeed I want to read the contents. The elements are accessed as you outlined Index 0 = first element